# What is wrong with my ctor using linked list and templates?

Tags: c++

I am trying to practice a little bit with cpp and want to make a class of linked list and than to manipulate it reverse it, finding circle and etc. but I can't understand what is the problem with my ctor/

I have this main:

```
#include "list.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main () {
  int x = 10;

  ListNode<int> node4();
  ListNode<int> node3(10 ,node4);
}
```

while this is "list.h" :

```
#ifndef LIST_NODE_H
#define LIST_NODE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ListNode {

  ListNode* next;
  T data;

 public:

  ListNode<T>( T dat = 0 ,const ListNode<T> &nex = NULL):data(dat),next(nex){};

};

#endif
```

I can't understand why this line: `ListNode<int> node3(10 ,node4);`
makes this errors, what is the problem?

> list.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: list.cpp:12:33: error: invalid
>   conversion from ‘ListNode (*)()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
>   list.h:15:3: error:   initializing argument 1 of
>   ‘ListNode::ListNode(T, const ListNode&) [with T = int]’
>   [-fpermissive] list.cpp:12:33: warning: passing NULL to non-pointer
>   argument 1 of ‘ListNode::ListNode(T, const ListNode&) [with T =
>   int]’ [-Wconversion-null] list.cpp:12:33: error: recursive evaluation
>   of default argument for ‘ListNode::ListNode(T, const ListNode&)
>   [with T = int]’ list.h:15:3: warning: in passing argument 2 of
>   ‘ListNode::ListNode(T, const ListNode&) [with T = int]’ [enabled
>   by default] list.h: In constructor ‘ListNode::ListNode(T, const
>   ListNode&) [with T = int]’: list.cpp:12:33:   instantiated from
>   here list.h:15:76: error: cannot convert ‘const ListNode’ to
>   ‘ListNode*’ in initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of errors with your code:

1. In your constructor you have a `null` reference as your default value, which is invalid (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364536/c-null-reference)).
2. For a constructor with no arguments you need to omit the `()` (you can read about why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no))

Something like this should work:

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ListNode {
    ListNode* next;
    T data;

    public:
          ListNode<T>( T dat = 0 ,ListNode<T> * nex = NULL):data(dat),next(nex){};
};


int main(){
    ListNode<int> node4;
    ListNode<int> node3(10, &node4);
}
```

Comment: Also it's probably a bad design to use linked list classes to store pointers to objects on the stack.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I completely agree with you on that one

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems here.

- First you don't need `ListNode<T>()` simpley `ListNode(...)` for the constructor.
- Second you can't have a defalut for a reference parameter to null if there is the potential for nex to be null it needs to be a pointer.

Comment: Yes you can have a default for a reference parameter, but you're right, he does need a pointer.

Comment: Not of null for a refrence.  and in this case it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters are evil (IMO).

(just a thought) 
Create different constructors (one with no parameters, one with parameters, ... )