# Is there one rule or priority to choose value/pointer/reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

how to choose value or pointer or reference?

when I code in c++, I don't have a clean idea when to choose each one?

Is there one priority or rule when choosing?

Comment: References have nicer syntax, but some people prefer how callers have to be explicit with pointers, and there are differences in the semantics (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c?rq=1)).

Comment: I agree with chris. I usually try to use references when possible. It looks a bit cleaner to me, usually a bit easier to debug as well.

Comment: IMHO, you should limit your use of pointers in "storing" heap objects. For any other uses, use references.

Comment: @MarkGarcia, But there's RAII for that :) (It uses pointers internally, though).

Comment: @chris It's implied. ;)

Comment: And also, pointers and references have their respective semantics and you should then use them only when the situation calls you to do so and when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

You use a value when

- Your data member is principal, i.e. not a copy of something else or a reference to another value
- You would like an independent copy that you would like to modify
- The object is much smaller than the pointer/reference, and you need many of them

You use pointers or references when

- The object is too large to copy efficiently
- The object needs to be modifiable in some other part of the code

You decide between a pointer and a reference using a simple rule: if there are situations where your referenced object does not exist, or the same variable must refer to different objects throughout its lifetime, use a pointer; otherwise, use a reference.

Comment: Do you think `std::optional` will replace your argument (at least an empty return) for using pointers come widespread C++14?

Comment: @chris I think `optional` is a bit different - it's similar to nullable value types of .NET. No doubt, the introduction of `optional` will displace some of the uses of pointers, but many more uses would remain.

Comment: Agreed. Admittedly, I don't use nullable types that often, but that might be because I don't use C# all that often yet.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight One of the main ones being calling interfaces of language agnostic or C APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try, just for others to correct me:

If it *really* can't be null, and you don't want to store it, and it's not primitive, use reference; If you don't need to change it, use const reference.

Otherwise, if you need to change it, or to store it, use pointer (better: smart pointers).
If it's not primitive, use `const` pointer.

If you need runtime polymorphism, you *must not* use pass-by-value.

Otherwise, use pass by value. use `int` and not `const int&`.

If you are writing a template, remember that passing by value (or copying in any way) implies a working copy-constructor as a constraint on the type. references might work wierd if the type is an array (or a string-literal).

Comment: +1: Your advice pretty much corresponds with my practice. The Q&A at [C++: null reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364536/c-null-reference) is insightful on your first point.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a small round-up of what I think is good practise concerning the selection of a type derived from arbitary T.

```
template <typename _T>
void CALLED (_T B) { /* _STUFF_ */ }

template <typename T>
void CALLER (void)
{
  T A;
  typedef T TYPE;
  CALLED<TYPE>(A);
}
```

TYPE can be one of the following:

- `T` (value type),
- `T&` (reference),
- `T` const & (reference to const T),
- `T*` (pointer),
- `T const *` (pointer to const T),
- `T const * const` (const pointer to const T),
- `T * const` (const pointer to non-const T)

Note: For the pointer types the call statement would change to `CALLED<TYPE>(&A);`.

### If `CALLED()` is intended to have a valid object

This should imho be somehow "default".

```
Guarantee to conserve A(^) |    no    |   yes   |     yes     |   yes   |
Alteration of B desired    |    yes   |   yes   |     no      |    no   |
sizeof(T) > sizeof(T*)     |  yes/no  |  yes/no |     yes     |    no   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE (of B)                |    T&    |    T    |  T const &  | T const |
```

(^): A "no" in this row can also mean that you want to alter A on purpose. I'll just have the optimal type depicted that conservation of A is guaranteed if this is not the case.

### If `CALLED()` can (and does) depict whether it gets a valid object

Since it is not very smart to bind a references to NULL and since a value parameter will always try to obtain an object,
we'll have to stick to pointers here.
Since call by value does not make much sense here, size of T is irrelevant.

```
Guarantee to conserve A(=*B) |    no    |       yes       |     yes     |    no   |
Alteration of B              |    no    |        no       |     yes     |   yes   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE                         | T* const | T const * const |  T const *  |    T*   |
```