# Set default parameter to nullptr and non-static class fields in C++

Tags: c++, default

I am building a binary search tree and the following is the add function:

```
void BinaryTree::add(int value, Node*& node, Node*& parent) {
    if(!node) {
        node = new Node(value);
        node->parent = parent;
    }
    else if(node->key < value)
        this->add(value, node->rightNode, node);
    else if(node->key > value)
        this->add(value, node->leftNode, node);
}
```

I want to set default parameters for the last two (node, parent) parameters:

```
void add(int value, Node*& node = root , Node*& parent = nullptr);
```

where root is a field of the class.

This does not seem to work for either case. How shall I implement it and what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: `void add(int value, Node* node = root , Node* parent = nullptr)`

Comment: @pwny Not if the OP wants to modify the pointers.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour You're right, although I have to admit that's probably not the best binary search tree design I've seen

Comment: References need to be initialized to a valid object, which means not a `nullptr`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364536/c-null-reference

Comment: I think I have to pass the pointers by reference since I am assigning values to the pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't initialize references to `nullptr`. They has to be valid objects. To make `root` defualt object you may add new function with same name

```
void BinaryTree::add(int value) {
    Node* emptyParent = nullptr;
    add(value, root, emptyParent); 
}
```