# Initializer list of reference wrappers

Tags: c++, c++11

I often encounter situations where I need to store lists of non-owning pointers or references to base class objects. Of course, I could do

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <list>

class Base {};

class Derived {};

class Container {
public:
    void setObjects(const std::initializer_list<const Base *> objects); // Set objects_ member
private:
    std::list<const Base *> objects_; // Should store Base and Derived objects
};
```

Using `std::reference_wrapper`, I could also use

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <list>
#include <functional> // for std::reference_wrapper

class Base {};

class Derived {};

class Container {
public:
    void setObjects(const std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<const Base> > objects); // Set objects_ member
private:
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<const Base> > objects_; // Should store Base and Derived objects
};
```

When I want to express the fact that an object (an instance of the `Container` class in my case) cannot exist without other objects (instances of the `Base` or `Derived` class), I tend to prefer the second alternative. However, it feels quite verbose to me and I have rarely seen it in other code. Is there any good reason I should prefer one alternative over the other?

Comment: The second alternative doesn't work: `std::reference_wrapper<anything &>` is invalid. You probably meant `std::reference_wrapper<const Base>`, without `&`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think correctness is more important than avoiding verboseness. At least for serious projects.

→ Always use `reference_wrapper<T>` over `T*` when `nullptr` should not be valid.

If it's *really* too verbose, you can always define a type alias with a shorter name:

```
template<typename type> using ref = std::reference_wrapper<type>;

std::list<ref<const int>> objects_;
```

Or just a "tag" helper type to document the intent:

```
template<typename type> using not_null = type;

std::list<not_null<const int*>> objects_;
```

There's also the [`gsl::not_null<T*>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/38eaf9fc95149ccdff17c6c0a9f0fbed15fc41f8/include/gsl.h#L63) class in the [Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL). For a related Q&A, see [gsl::not_null<T*> vs. std::reference_wrapper<T> vs. T&](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33306553/3425536).