# With std::optional standardizing, can we stop using nullptr in new code and deprecate it?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, idioms, nullptr

From time immemorial, when passing pointers to or from functions, we tend to special-case the null pointer:

```
 p = get_pointer_to_the_foo(args);
 if (p == nullptr) { /* foo is inaccessible, do one thing */ }
 else { /* we can access foo, do something else */ }
```

and this is an inheritance from C. Now, we occasionally would do the same with other types, e.g. using a signed type to represent either a valid non-negative value, and, say, -1 or to indicate an error.

The latter pattern will now be finally deprecated with the onset of `std::optional`:  `std::optional<unsigned>` is either `nullopt` or a non-negative value. But - what about pointers? After all, `nullptr` is just one of innumerable invalid pointer values. So, when writing new code (when all of it is C++17) - should we essentially forget about it, and pass around either `std::optional<foo_t*>`'s or assumed-non-null `foo_t *`'s?

Comment: `std::optional<foo*>` doesn't make much sense. Did you mean `std::optional<foo&>`?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: No, I meant what I wrote. Think about it; it does actually make sense.

Comment: `std::optional<foo*>` means that the pointer itself could not exist. It's "similar" to `foo**`, not to `foo*`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Either you have a pointer - a _valid_ pointer - or no pointer at all. Whereas before we 'simulated' "no pointer" with the nullptr value.

Comment: Consider `std::optional<foo*> x`. If `x != nullopt`, there's nothing that guarantees `*x != nullptr`. Why do you assume that `x` would be a *valid* pointer?

Comment: In a way all pointers are currently 'optional', i.e. nullptr is considered one of their valid values. If you'd like to clarify that confusion using a type system, you'd want the opposite of `std::optional`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Oh, but it's exactly the other way around. Now we no longer have to make that silly assumption. We can say that we only ever have valid pointers! We never have to set a pointer to an invalid value again - since we can use nullopt for when we failed to obtain a valid pointer for something.

Comment: @Kos: So what I'm saying is, we can be rid of that anomaly. Stop treating pointers that way. From now on (if we so choose) there are only valid pointers, ever, period. And if you're not sure you can pass a valid pointer, use an `std::optional`.

Comment: @einpoklum: that's a very optimistic view. Sometimes you don't have control over the pointers that are passed to your function. Also, again, you're adding an extra "layer of optionality" - what you want is `T&` instead of pointers and `optional<T&>` for optional references.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: It's not an extra layer, it's replacing the existing layer. Also, I'm talking about code that will be written in the future, based on C++17 and onwards (say, maybe the v2 of the standard library). So it's up to us decide how code is to behave. As for invalid pointers being passed - that's also a problem now, if we get `0xDEADBEEF` instead of something meaningful.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*It's not an extra layer, it's replacing the existing layer.*" But it's not replacing anything because *it's still there*. `nullptr` still exists and will be used. `optional<T*> t = (T*)nullptr;` is still valid code, and in order for a function that takes `optional<T*>` to not be broken, it *must* check this possibility.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The whole point of the question is that we could, perhaps, stop using nullptr, since with `std::optional` being in the language, it can be decided it is no longer used. Of course I'm talking about new code, not old code, C APIs etc.

Comment: @einpoklum how about [`not_null<T*>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306553/gslnot-nullt-vs-stdreference-wrappert-vs-t)?

Comment: @Quentin: We will no longer need it. It's redundant. There will only be valid pointers. The concept of a null pointer can be deprecated (again, ignoring existing code).

Comment: @einpoklum: Who would decide that? How would it be decided? What about all of the APIs that exist in the standard presently that deal with NULL pointers? Not to mention all of the APIs that exist in other libraries. It's absurd to even consider that `optional<T*>` could somehow replace NULL pointers.

Comment: @NicolBolas: So, yours is a valid argument against: "Too much legacy and out-of-language conventions to do this". You can make that an answer.

Comment: Almost all pointer values are not valid pointers. Consider: `auto stream_ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::istream *>(0xDEADBEEF); int i; (*stream_ptr) >> i;` Unless you know that *somebody* initialised an `istream` there, you've got UB

Comment: @Caleth: That's a perfectly valid pointer value - it's the memroy address`0xDEADBEEF`. The pointed-to memory may not be valid; or the memory region may not have been allocated, but that's not a problem with the pointer. In other words - if we were to write a function which takes a pointer, and you got `0xDEADBEEF`, there would be nothing you can do (inherent to the language, or the standard library) to check whether it's valid except dereference it.

Comment: @einpoklum it is a perfectly valid `void*`, but it is not a valid `T*` **for all T**

Comment: @Caleth: Granted, but there's nothing special about `0x0` in this respect. Worrying about a pointer to an unconstructed T is a concern now and will be a concern in the same way if we deprecated the use of nullptr and used `std::optional<T*>` instead.

Comment: @einpoklum the point is that the appropriate replacement for `T*` in the scenario "We might have a `T` for you" is `optional<T&>`, not `optional<T*>`

Comment: @Caleth: So you're saying that perhaps we could forego the use of non-void pointers altogether? Hmm.

Comment: An 'always valid pointer' (assuming no complications like ownership) is, to me, a reference. So, if you want to put it in a container, use `std::reference_wrapper<T>`. There: no default constructibility with an undefined value, no `null` state, no accidental arithmetic, etc. Then if it's optional, use `std::optional< std::reference_wrapper<T> >`. *Or*, if you want the ability to maintain a `null` state but don't want that other stuff I mentioned, use the proposed `observer_ptr<T>`.

Comment: @underscore_d: A reference isn't mutable, and you don't do arithmetic with it.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer embed the optional semantic already. Therefore `std::optional<T*>` would be redundant to say the least and the introduction of said feature won't impact much raw pointers.

This is also true with `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` all of which can also be `nullptr`.

Just like with any new feature we have to ponder what's pragmatic versus our innate urge to use it everywhere it's feasible.

Comment: A pointer doesn't embed the optional semantic already; we've arbitrarily "sacrificing" one of the possible addresses in memory and interpreting it as a poor man's `nullopt`. Now, we no longer have to do that.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*A pointer doesn't embed the optional semantic already*" How is checking against `nullptr` any different from checking against `nullopt`? Pointers very much do "embed the optional semantic".

Comment: @NicolBolas: Oh, a _big_ difference : (1) No arbitrary if'ing, just case class decomposition (although we don't have syntax for that right now). (2) Uniformity in the use of optional semantic for all types (3) No longer sacrificing any address in the address space, so we can safely use address 0x0 . Granted (3) is a minor point, but (1) is big language-design-wise IMHO.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*Uniformity in the use of optional semantic for all types*" Which can easily be achieved by making a global template function to handle such tests for both `optional<T>` and `T*`. Or any other types that a user might want to add. "*No longer sacrificing any address in the address space, so we can safely use address 0x0 .*" The null pointer constant does not have to have the value zero. Furthermore, just because C++ isn't using NULL pointers doesn't mean the compiler won't. After all, C++ still has to link with C code.

Answer (score 1):

As I think my conversation in comments is not sufficient I provide answer to einpoklum comment. This answer is more like suplement to Nir Friedman [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43049461/2483065).

Please read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer. Pointer is a type. It's have state describe as Null pointer. Pointer is not a CPU's memory address (but it could be implemented like that), it is abstract type that instance point to another object. Most of pointers has relations with corresponding type but not all of them as you can point by void pointer to any object.

Answer (score 0):

Because all pointer types can be null, this unfortunately doesn't make sense in C++. You would need people to accept, by convention, that:

```
unique_ptr<Foo> make_foo();
```

Never returns a null pointer, even though it can. But then you'd wonder, if the author actually followed the convention, so you'd look at the docs anyway. And if this function never returns `nullptr`, then the docs should say it anyhow. And if it can, the docs should say it also.

Basically, the idea behind `optional` is to use the type system to protect people. Particularly to encourage people to write types that are constructed into a valid state immediately. In other words, people often used to write types that were effectively `OptionalFoo`, because they weren't always in a valid state. So instead, encourage people to write `Foo`, and use `optional<Foo>` when they need it. That way, the type `Foo` is *always* valid.

However, pointers, raw and smart, just cannot be guaranteed to be in a valid state. Every pointer is already an optional pointer. We can argue over the exact meaning of validity here, but basically you have a precondition on calling `*` on all pointers. The whole point of `optional` is to *remove* preconditions; you don't need to call `f.is_valid()` because you wrote a `Foo` instead of an `OptionalFoo`.

By the way, the reason why pointers cannot make this guarantee in C++ is actually rooted in the absence of destructive move in C++. If you try to write a `not_null_unique_ptr`, what would the move constructor look like?

Comment: Nir, `make_unique()` _always_ returns a valid pointer (wrapped in an `std::unique_ptr`. So if you write a `make_foo()`, you should be doing the same even today - throwing `std::bad_alloc()` on failure.

Comment: @einpoklum *If* it returns, then yes, it does. But that is covered by documentation, it's not enforced by the type system in any way. I'm starting to get the sense from your response to the answers posted (both of which are pretty reasonable) that your "question" is really you trying to argue that we should do a certain thing.

Comment: The "nullness" of pointers is not represented in the type system. There are no null types, or a null pointer type, there's just "pointer". And nullness is not inherent in it, it's artificial. Absolutely no reason why I can't use any address in the address space (well, other than not having enough memory of course).

Comment: @einpoklum No, that is not true. Pointers have a well defined hole in the type system (sadly). Dereferencing a null pointer is *not* just dereferencing an address that probably has garbage. It is actually defined as undefined behavior. You may not like that pointers encode optionality, or wish they didn't, but the standard officially sanctions their optionality.

Comment: Now _that_ is an answer to my question (as opposed to what you've written above). If you can elaborate in your answer how pointers are treated differently in the type system that would be great. Note that if it's just undefined behavior for `*((void *) 0x0)`, that could become defined in the next standard.

Comment: @einpoklum I was taking it as a given that dereferencing a null pointer is a null pointer is UB. I feel like you probably knew that already, so I didn't get into it. My last few sentences already explains pretty well why it cannot just "become defined" in the next standard. You simply cannot have good smart pointers without destructive move or optionality of some kind.

Comment: @einpoklum you are thinking of pointers in integer categories and that's just wrong. Pointers can have invalid values that you cannot use to allocate memory and it's not important if it's one value (ex. 0) or multiple of them. Think of float that have multiple NaN values and no one is arguing about not using whole 32bit space of values to represent correct number.

Comment: @Logman: That's not inherent in the type; it's a platform restriction (or maybe even a runtime restriction). If I have an embedded platform with 4GB of byte-addressable memory, why isn't every address a valid value for a pointer?

Comment: @einpoklum because **almost all** of the objects that would be pointed to by those pointers haven't been constructed. None of the invariants of the types of those objects would hold. Well done, you've just blown a **massive hole** in the capability to reason about programs.

Comment: @einpoklum ok then let me explain something. In computer word you could be restricted to some boundaries. In ex. right now you actually can't address whole memory as you are restricted to addressing 8 bit words (on x86). If you want to address 4GB of data you need bigger pointers. This is just how it's works. What about addressing 5GB of data etc. there always will be restrictions as that how discrete not infinite machines works. Pointer to type is just another type and instance of it has it's own states and transactions.

Comment: @Caleth: See my reply to your similar comment above. No hole is blown, the same hole exists now except that you special-case address `0x0` by checking for nullptr.

Comment: @Logman: It's not "just how it works". And, again, this has nothing to do with the type, these are platform restrictions which the language is unconcerned with even now.