# How to rewrite with boost::optional in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-optional, stdoptional

How do I rewrite the following code to use `boost::optional` or `boost::none`, in C++11?

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<FooBase> find( std::string key)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<FooBase>(void)> > m{
                       {"key1", [](){return std::make_unique<BarDerived>();} },
                       {"key2", [](){return std::make_unique<BarDerived1>();} } };
                                        
    auto it = m.find(key);
    if (it != std::end(m))
        return (it->second());  
    else 
        return nullptr;                                        

}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether I would wrap a smart pointer into an `optional`. `std::unique_ptr` already has a `null`-state, so you would basically double that. Imagine: `if (foo && *foo)` is required to make sure the optional has a value and the wrapped smart pointer is alive...

Comment: make_unique is not c++11 btw

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299607/mix-boostoptional-and-stdunique-ptr) helps

Comment: also you might consider not using std::function at all, switching to unordered_map and if you're able to use c++17 switching to string_view : https://godbolt.org/z/xEvG5P compare the disassmbly of all 3 versions and see for yourself

Comment: @Yamahari before C++17 you can already use [boost::string_ref](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html) or [boost::string_view](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/boost/utility/string_view.hpp)

Answer (score 1):

So, you want this to return a value type instead of a pointer?

That isn't possible with `boost::optional` (or `std::optional` in c++17), because of [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). For a value type, you can only return as much information as `FooBase` contains, so you'll lose information when you upcast from one of the derived types.

For this though, you can use another Boost type that got adopted by the C++17 standard: `boost::variant`. This is a type-safe [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) that can hold one of a set of types in the same memory space. Just add a type to represent "none" (`std::monostate`'s purpose in C++17, and `boost::blank`'s purpose in Boost), and then add each derived type:

```cpp
struct Bar1 { };
struct Bar2 { };
using Bar = boost::variant<boost::blank, Bar1, Bar2>;
```

Then you can rewrite your function like this:

```cpp
Bar find( std::string key)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<Bar()> > m {
        {"key1", [](){return Bar1 {}; } },
        {"key2", [](){return Bar2 {}; } } 
    };
                                        
    auto it = m.find(key);
    if (it != std::end(m))
        return (it->second());  
    else 
        return { }; // default-constructs the first variant, in this case blank
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dcYevv