# std::ref and swap function does not seem to work well together

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <typename T>
void myswap(T a,T b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
int main()
{
  int m(20),n(30); 
  myswap(ref(m),ref(n));
  //m is still 20 and n is still 30
}
```

Why have not the values of m and n interchanged? Passing a value wrapped in `std::ref` to an INCREMENT function results in value change in the original variable (variable in the stack frame that calls INCREMENT function). Or, Is `std::ref` usage is restricted/limited?

Answer (score 8):

`std::ref` (and its associated `std::reference_wrapper`) is a tool designed for very specific use cases in the standard library and should only be used for those; if you want to use it in your own places, you have to understand it in detail and respect what it does.

Fundamentally, a `reference_wrapper` is much closer to a pointer than a reference. So substitute a pointer in your swap function and you'll see that there's no reason to assume that it would actually swap:

```
void myswap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int* temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: The first sentence is slightly misleading. Of course `std::ref` is not limited to the standard library (as you also note it after it)

Answer (score 4):

Your code creates two temporary `std::reference_wrapper` objects and swaps them, so they refer to different objects. All that happens is you swap two `reference_wrapper` objects, not their targets.

If you manually write what the function template will generate the reason for the behaviour should be obvious:

```
void myswap(std::reference_wrapper<int> a, std::reference_wrapper<int> b)
{
  std::reference_wrapper<int> temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = a;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't change the `int` objects, only the `reference_wrapper` objects.

If what you're trying to do is force `myswap` to take references you need to call `myswap<int&>(m, n)`, you can't emulate that by using `reference_wrapper`. But you should really fix `myswap`, because it's pretty useless the way it's written now.

Comment: Indeed, but should not the temporary be pointing to m and n created in the penultimate stack frame?. Pass a variable wrapped in std::ref to a increment function and you will see the value wud have updated. Ain't a temporary created in increment function? Then, how the change is reflected in original variable.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, it DOES take 'by value'.
template <typename T>
void incrementer(T a)
{
    ++a;
}
int a = 20;
incrementer(ref(a));
//a is 21 now

Comment: `reference_wrapper` doesn't support an increment operator, so the increment function causes a conversion to `int&` and increments the target. The swap function only uses the copy constructor and copy assignment, which `reference_wrapper` _does_ support, so those operations work on the `reference_wrapper` directly, not on the target.

Comment: **No it doesn't**.  Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/reference_wrapper/ and tell me where you see `operator++` declared. The `++bar` excample cause a conversion to `int&` and increments  the `int`. Read my previous comment again. "Incrementing a reference_wrapper" doesn't make sense, so instead it changes the thing it refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Your `myswap` takes the elements by *value*.

Essentially you swap the two references (`std::reference_wrapper` s) at the local scope of the function.

The values they point to won't change.

---

```
template <typename T> void incrementer(T a) { ++a; } int a = 20;
```

In this case there's a conversion to `int&` [with](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
operator T& () const noexcept { return *_ptr; }
```

In your code, on the other hand:

```
T temp = a;
```

will simply call the copy constructor, which copies the underlying pointer:

```
reference_wrapper(const reference_wrapper&) noexcept = default;
```

then, on the next lines you again copy the pointer:

```
reference_wrapper& operator=(const reference_wrapper& x) noexcept = default;
```

Comment: @Karoly: I am passing a reference_wrapper<int> to the function. not plain integer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766939/difference-between-stdreference-wrapper-and-simple-pointer?lq=1 (about reference_wrapper and its benefits).

Comment: @101010: Isn't that what I was saying? Let me edit to make it obvious.

Comment: Yes, they take elements (of type std::ref) by value. But a copy for m and n is not created in myswap function. The two new references are still pointing to m & n created in penultimate stack frame.

Comment: Yes... We agree on all that.

Comment: @DIVAKARVENKATRAMANI, yes of course, I don't understand why you expect anything different. Maybe my answer makes it clear.