# Nested struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I tried to write a program with the following `struct` declaration:

```
struct N
{
    int value;
    N Left;
    N Right;
};
```

If that was possible, there would be an infinite number of structs in my program. I still want my *Left* and *Right* to have the exact same structure as N. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You know that it's impossible, you even know *why* it's impossible, but you're still looking for a way to do it?

Comment: Recursion.  *"Pete and Repeat were on a boat.  Pete fell off.  Who was left?"*  How does the compiler know when to stop the recursive layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build tree-like structures you may use pointers:

```
struct N {
    int value;
    N *left;
    N *right;
};
```

You may also use references:

```
struct N {
    int value;
    N &left;
    N &right;
};
```

but this way you'll need to carefully bind references in elements that don't have either of branches (or both.)

Or other indirecting types: `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `reference_wrapper`, etc.

Additionally, you can have a whole bunch of child referencnes:

```
struct N {
    int value;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<N>> branches;
};
```

Comment: No, you cannot use references. References must bind to a valid object at their initialization (Construction). Therefore it this will cause invalid references.

Comment: @GillBates they *could*, if they use a constructor. But it would probably not be very useful.

Comment: @GillBates `N wat{42, wat, wat};`? Or declare an `external N null;` and default `left` and `right` to it?

Comment: @bipll [reference_wrappers, unlike pointers, don't have a null state.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766939/difference-between-stdreference-wrapper-and-simple-pointer)

Comment: Yes, but can be rebound. Btw it's not hard to define a refernce wrapper that _has_ null state.

Comment: Technicalities aside, it's just a bad idea to have nodes made out of references. Why offer it as advice?

Comment: @PasserBy Sure, still possible. :)

Comment: Besides, there are so many class hierarchies in this world where objects contain pointers to other objects, and those pointers aren't expected to be null.

Comment: Thank you! May I also ask you I should initialise such an object? I need to tell the computer not to expect further delcarations from a particular struct at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I think im getting what your goal is. You want a struct that is aware of its neighbours. In that case use pointer instead.

```
struct N
{
    int value;
    N* Left;
    N* Right;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What is happening in your case is that the compiler is trying to generate your struct, but cannot because of infinite recursion:      `sizeof(N) = sizeof(int) + sizeof(N)`

A way to solve this is to **use pointers** to N. Now : `sizeof(N) = sizeof(int) + 2*sizeof(N*)` is defined.

```
struct N { int value; N *left, *right; };
```

If you are using `C++17`, you can also use `std::optional` and `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
struct N { int value; std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<N>> left, right; };
```

**Do Not Use References.**
References must bind during initialization and must bind to a valid object. Therefore, some of your references are bound to be invalid (since the tree is not infinite).

Comment: The `optional` example is incorrect, it would have infinite size too (`optional` is like the type with a validity flag tacked on)

Comment: @M.M You are right. I assumed it was implemented as a pointer :). How about `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` thought?

Comment: Legal but I don't really see the advantage over `N *`. (It probably uses more storage, and is more cumbersome to access, for no clear benefit)