# Why doesn't std::swap swap underlying objects of std::reference_wrapper?

Tags: c++

**Background:**

I am trying to implement a function, let's call it `mysort`, that takes variable number of arguments of same type and sort them. For example the code below should print `1 2 3`

```
template <typename ... Args>
void mysort(Args& ... args);
int main(int, char**)
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 2;
    mysort(x, y, z);
    cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**What I have tried:**

Here is the solution I came up with

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void mysort(T& t, Args& ... args)
{
    constexpr size_t n = sizeof...(Args) + 1;
    std::array<std::reference_wrapper<T>, n> temp = { std::ref(t), std::ref(args)... };
    std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
}
```

But this solution doesn't work because what `std::swap` does with `std::reference_wrapper` is not what I expect (I expect any changes to `std::reference_wrapper` should change the object for which `std::reference_wrapper` was created).

Everything starts working after [adding](https://godbolt.org/z/je9qh5x1c)

```
namespace std
{
    void swap(std::reference_wrapper<int>& a, std::reference_wrapper<int>& b) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(a.get(), b.get());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the standard requires `std::sort` to use `std::swap`, so I think this is not a complete solution and is implementation-dependent.

**Summarizing:**

My idea of a std::reference_wrapper is that it should behave just like a reference, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here are my questions:

1. What is the best way to implement `mysort`?
2. Why doesn't the standard provide a `std::swap` specification for `std::reference_wrapper` that would swap underlying objects?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Before std::swap, operator= already doesn't do what you think: it rebinds (on purpose).

Comment: `temp` will end up being a sorted list of references to your original variables https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%3D. `std::reference` wrapper doesn't behave like a reference, it allows storing a reference where it wouldn't normally be possible to store one, to do that it needs to be copyable/assignable

Comment: *My idea of a std::reference_wrapper is that it should behave just like a reference, but that doesn't seem to be the case.*  That is, indeed, not the case.

Comment: The actual use case wants something else: Usualy you use a container of reference wrappers because you cant have a contianer of references and then you want `std::sort` to shuffle the elements in the container not what they refer to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of `std::reference_wrapper` is that it is copyable and assignable, "assignable" in the sense that a reference wrapper can be rebound to a new value the way that a normal reference cannot.

You're doing the opposite of what it is intended for. In your case when the implementation of `std::sort` swaps items in the temporary array it is rebinding the references, but this is not what you want. You want it to swap the actual items not the references.

One way to do this would be to let `std::sort` sort copies of the arguments and then assign them back to your reference arguments in sorted order:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void mysort(T& t, Args& ... args)
{
    constexpr size_t n = sizeof...(Args) + 1;
    std::array<T, n> temp = { t, args... };
    std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    std::tie(t, args...) = std::tuple_cat(temp);
}
```

Here I wrap them in a tuple so I can assign via `std::tie`. There may be some way to do this with fewer copies, but this is what came to mind.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, `std::reference_wrapper` is an old poorly designed class that currently serves certain simple purposes, like in `std::bind/bind_front` or in construction of `std::thread`, where it is used to imply that the variables aren't copied but taken by reference. And one creates them via `std::ref/cref`.

I just don't recommend ever using `std::reference_wrapper` aside from template cases where it is used to tell the difference whether user wants to forward a copy or a reference to the object.

If you want a reference imitating class that performs an assign/move-through rather than rebind that's up to you to implement. Just you should be aware that it can be problematic in certain situations.

Also don't ever write any kind of

```
namespace std
{
    void swap(std::reference_wrapper<int>& a, std::reference_wrapper<int>& b) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(a.get(), b.get());
    }
}
```

It might break a lot of code that you import.

Comment: In what way is `std::reference_wrapper` poorly designed? It does exactly what it needs to do and no more? Extra functionality would be wasteful in the use cases it was designed for

Comment: @AlanBirtles it was designed way before `std::thread` and `std::bind` existed. And it just failed to find any proper use. It was simply reused for these objects as it fitted their construction scheme.

Comment: Actually `boost::bind`, `boost::thread` and `boost::ref` were all released at the same time in version 1.25.0 https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/. Even if it did predate them it doesn't mean it's poorly designed. You still haven't stated what's poor about it's design?

Comment: @AlanBirtles the class doesn't do anything useful, except for this specific purpose which makes it more of an internal service class rather than an API that should be exposed to users.

Comment: It fulfills that purpose exactly as needed though so seems perfectly designed? Maybe you actually mean the language is poorly designed making this class necessary?

Comment: @AlanBirtles you again miss the point. The problem is that the class shouldn't be a part of the stl's API. Also, the cases, where it helps were obsolute too as they were added together with introduction of lambdas, making them largely pointless addition.

Comment: Maybe I am just being stupid, who knows but I myself have used `std:: reference_wrapper` in the implementation of some classes and it made my code simpler by not having to implement it myself so it seems to be that's it's neither poorly designed or obsolete. You've still not justified what about it is poorly designed

Comment: @AlanBirtles just replace it with raw pointer. Or an `observer_ptr` if you want to be fancy or the codebase has bad practice of calling new/delete manually.

Comment: But a pointer doesn't have the same semantics, it can be null for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766939/what-is-the-difference-between-stdreference-wrapper-and-a-simple-pointer

Comment: @AlanBirtles you cannot just replace it with raw pointer. But its not like something requires complex change. It's purely cosmetics. That the reference wrapper cannot be null but is rebindable, makes it weird. Normally, one ought to have neither or both.

Comment: Beyond being nullable, raw pointers need to be deferenced to get a value out of them so they won't work as stand-ins for their values in standard algorithms and containers. Now you could wrap them in a struct and define the operations you need on the struct, but then you are just implementing your own version of reference_wrapper.

Comment: @jwezorek I've never seen `reference_wrapper` being used in standart algos. And there is no point in using them in containers as they function as pointers with mildly different syntax.