# specify default value of std::function

Tags: c++, lambda

```
void func(const std::function<void()>& f = empty)
{
    if(f)
        f();
}
```

what is the 'empty' should be? I use `[](){}` . But technically, that is not empty, the f() will execute.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
void func(const std::function<void()>& f = {}) {
    if(f) f();
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68fb241d1159bf2b)

Comment: @suzuiyue What do you mean?

Comment: I do not see bool cast or ! operator overload in [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). So why if(f) or if (!f) works?

Comment: @suzuiyue I am just getting into std::funtion now, but I would assume it's because it was created as a C++ alternative to C-style function pointers, where you check whether or not the fp is null, and f would be a function pointer to the unnamed function created by the lambda. Someone can correct me here if I'm wrong.

Comment: @suzuiyue http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool

Answer (score 22):

```
const std::function<void()>& f = nullptr
```

or

```
const std::function<void()>& f = std::function<void()>()
```

Comment: Yes, and the default `std::function` is throwing some exception (I forgot which one)....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch but OP's code checks the function to see if it's empty before calling. Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:- Looking for this one: `1/ An exception of type bad_function_call is thrown by function::operator() (20.8.11.2.4) when the function wrapper object has no target.` ?

Comment: [nullptr reference is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364586/5393174)

Comment: @kgbook not sure that it's what you meant, but `const std::function<void()>& f = nullptr` is totally valid. `function& operator=( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept` is defined and drops the current target, making the function empty.

Answer (score 10):

I would use a nullptr for the empty case. It can be used because you never use full function objects but only pointers to them, so `func(f1);` will be in fact  `func(&f1)` => you will always pass pointers to func, so `nullptr` is IMHO the best candidate.

This compiles and run:

```
void func(const std::function<void()>& f = nullptr)
{
    if(f)
        f();
}
```

The alternative of using a default function would be:

```
void func(const std::function<void()>& f = std::function<void()>()) {
    try {
        f();
    }
    catch(std::bad_function_call e) {
    }
}
```

using exception catching. The choice between the 2 mainly depends on whether you expect the empty case to occur; almost never: go with exception vs. sometimes: test before call.

As question mentions `if (f)`, use `nullptr`

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
const std::function<void()> & f = std::function<void()>()
```

As Basile added, the standard says:

> § 20.8.11.1 Class bad_function_call [func.wrap.badcall]
>
> 1/ An exception of type bad_function_call is thrown by
>   function::operator() (20.8.11.2.4) when the function wrapper object
>   has no target.