# Can we use extends with Has a relationship

Tags: java, oop

We use `extends` keyword for using `is-a relationship` in Java using OOP. But on the other side, we also have `has-a relationship` and we use reference of the first class in 2nd class for `has-a relationship`. My question is, if we have a has-a relationship, can we use `extends keyword` in implementation?

Suppose we have the example here:

> A “university” has several “departments”. Without the existence of
>   “university”, there is no chance for the “departments” to exist.

Can we write it as (just a rough example for understanding)

```
class University extends Department
{
   Department d = new Department();
   University(String name, Department d)
    {
        this.Name=name;
        this.Department = d;    
    }    
}
```

or when we make an entity of one class in another we can not use word `extends`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: I guess you can but that’s what implements is for.

Comment: Your design compiles, so it is possible. But why do you need to extend from `Department`. The class also works without it.

Comment: I was just thinking that this 'extends' keyword in Java is only for 'is-a relationship' or for any kind of inheritance including has a relationship

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it with `extends`, but you could use an `interface`, as follows:

```
interface HasDepartments {
    public Set<Departments> getDepartments();
}

class University implements HasDepartments {
    private final String name;
    private final Set<Department> departments = new HashSet<Department>();
    University(String name, Collection<Department departments) {
        this.name=name;
        this.departments = departments;    
    }
    public Set<Departments> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }
 }
```

However, unless there were other things that could have departments, I wouldn't bother. Just `University` having a `getDepartments()` method is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, again in my question, Can we use 'extends' keyword when we have 'has-a relationship'.

Comment: @AHF as per the first sentence in my answer *you can't do it with `extends`*... no.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see this link, to understand difference between is-a and has-a relationship
[What is the difference between IS -A relationship and HAS-A relationship? Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162714/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-relationship-and-has-a-relationship-java)

also search for composition, aggregation, association in java (has-a relationship types)

to answer your question, There is no obstacle to use it but you need a good reason to inherit University from Department.