# c++ nested class getter and setter does not work

Tags: c++

I'm making a pokemon battle code. Here are codes that I've made.
First, I define Pokemon class.

(pokemon.h)

```
class Pokemon{ ... 
private:
    int hp;
public:
    int gethp();
    void sethp(int n); 
...}
```

(pokemon.cpp)

```
... 
int Pokemon::gethp(){return hp;}
void Pokemon::sethp(int n){hp = n;} 
...
```

Next, I define Trainer class. Trainer has a list of pokemons.

(trainer.h)

```
class Trainer: public Pokemon {
private:
    Pokemon pokemons[3];
...
public:
    Pokemon getpokemon(int n);
    void setpokemons(int n, int m, int i);
...
```

(trainer.cpp)

```
Pokemon Pikachu(..., 160, ...)               //Pikachu's hp is defined to be 160.
...
Pokemon makepokemon(int n) {        
    if (n == 1) { return Pikachu; }
....
}
Pokemon Trainer::getpokemon(int n) { return pokemons[n-1]; }
void Trainer::setpokemons(int n, int m, int i) {
    pokemons[0] = makepokemon(n);
    pokemons[1] = makepokemon(m);
    pokemons[2] = makepokemon(i);
}
...
```

Now, when I use gethp/sethp in the main fucntion, I have a problem.

(main part)

```
Trainer me;
me.setpokemons(1, ...);           // My first pokemon is pikachu then.

...

cout << me.getpokemon(1).gethp();             //This gives 160.
me.getpokemon(1).sethp(80);                   //I want to change Pikachu's hp into 80.
cout << me.getpokemon(1).gethp();             //Still this gives 160.
```

The problem is that sethp is not working. I guess that I need to use call by reference at some point to fix this, but I don't get how I should do.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: please post real code, a [mcve]. Code that you made incorrect by introducing syntax errors all over the place is of little use when we want to help you with your real code.

Comment: You're on the right track, but you don't need *call* by reference, you need to *return* a reference. (Although I think an interface with `increaseHp` and `decreaseHp` would be more better. Getters and setters are not-nice.)

Comment: `class Trainer: public Pokemon {` if `Trainer` inherits from `Pokemon`, you're saying that a Trainer *is a* Pokemon. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry my real code contains other many information so it is very long. So I've just posted the minimal amount of contents.

Comment: No. Trainer is not a Pokemon.But it has a list of three pokemons. Is the nested structure wrong?

Comment: Which reference should  I return? I have multiple objects so it's difficult for me to decide what I need to change.

Comment: @MoonJuHong if Trainer is not a Pokemon, then it should not inherit from Pokemon. Read more on "is-a" vs "has-a" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36162730/2602718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
me.getpokemon(1).sethp(80)
```

Let's walk through this--you're calling `me.getpokemon(1)`, which returns a copy of a  `Pokemon` from `me`'s `pokemons` array. You then call `sethp` on the copy, setting its `hp` to 80. And then, since the copy isn't saved anywhere, you never see it again until it's destroyed...

What you want instead, is to cause `getpokemon(1)` to return a *reference* to the `pokemons` item insetad of a copy, so that when you call `sethp()`, you're modifying the original. You can do that by changing the function to return a reference instead of a copy:

```
Pokemon& Trainer::getpokemon(int n) { return pokemons[n-1]; }
//    ^^^
```

Comment: Oh I was changing nothing in the previous way. Okay, now I'm getting not the copy, but its reference so that I can change them. Now I see the picture. Thank you for your clear explanation!