# Jetpack Compose: close application by button

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

NavController can't pop programmatically the latest @Composable in the stack. I.e. popBackStack() doesn't work if it's a root page. So the application can be closed by tap on "Close" button view and only hardware Back key allows to leave application.

Example: Activity

```
class AppActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(state: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(state)
        setContent {
            val controller = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(controller, startDestination = HOME) {
                composable(HOME) { HomePage(controller) }
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomePage.kt

```
@Composable
fun HomePage(controller: NavController) {
    Button(onClick = {
        controller.popBackStack()
    }) {
        Text("Exit")
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How to close the app in onClick handler if Compose Navigation is used.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically
In Compose you have to pass the activity through to the composable that will use it.

Comment: We do not know how the framework uses and cashes the @Composable entities. I mean, we do not manage its lifecycle, so there is risk of the Context leak.

Comment: Posted an issue/question to Google tracker
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187134652

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomePage(controller: NavController) {
    val activity = (LocalContext.current as? Activity)
    Button(onClick = {
        activity?.finish()
    }) {
        Text("Exit")
    }
}
```

Comment: After few months in production, I can say this solution works good. Thank you.

Comment: Getting activity inside composable is not a good idea. It's better to flow up the event to ViewModel, subscribe to it in the activity and then call finish there

Comment: ..or even better: call onClick = { onExitClick() } which is passed as a lambda to the function fun HomePage(onExitClick: () -> Unit) {}

Comment: Casting local context to Activity is unsafe. Passing a lambda to compose and trigger back to the hosted activity seems to be the best solution.

Comment: I agree with you guys that pass a lambda might be a better option and of course this solution only works if you're following single activity model.. But here it goes an honest question: Do you guys see a scenario where the local context is not an Activity?

Comment: @nglauber Yes, it might be a `Fragment`.

Comment: @MinasMina a `Fragment` **is not** a `Context` (since it does not extends from `Context`) a `Fragment` **has** a `Context`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162714/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-relationship-and-has-a-relationship-in

Comment: @nglauber You are correct. :)

Comment: I have honestly never come into a situation where the composable context isn't an activity. They always start with an activity. Just don't cast it to a specific activity

Comment: you may get class cast exception

Comment: yes my app really closes when I use this approach but it closes due to java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity, so it's better to use the approach from @DmytroMarchuk and yes I cast the context to a normal activity like this: (context as Activity).finish()

Answer (score 4):

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity:AppCompatActivity() {

  @ExperimentalAnimatedInsets
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    val activityKiller: () -> Unit = {
      this.finish()
    }

    setContent {
      MainAppEntry(activityKiller = activityKiller)
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun MainAppEntry(activityKiller: () -> Unit) {
  val mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel<MainViewModel>()
  //mutableStateOf .......
  var isKillRequested = mainViewModel.mainActivityState.isActivityFinishRequested
  if (isKillRequested) {
    activityKiller()
    return
  }

  Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    TextButton(onClick = {
      mainViewModel.smuaActivityState.requestActivityFinish()
    }) {
      Text(text = "Kill app")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`finishAffinity()` closes your app and **keeps** it in the ***Recent apps*** screen

`finishAndRemoveTask()` closes your app and **removes** it from the ***Recent apps*** screen

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this by passing the *finish()* function from the main Activity down to my component

**Activity:**

```
NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = AppScreens.MainMenu.name
        ) {
            composable(route = AppScreens.MainMenu.name) {
                MainMenuScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                    onExit = { finish()}
                )
            }
        }
```

**Component:**

```
@Composable
fun MainMenuScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    onExit: () -> Unit
) { 
...
Button(
         modifier = Modifier,
         onClick = {onExit()}
      )
```