Android studio preview isn't rendering
When I try to render a preview of my code I get this error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to class android.app.Activity (com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext and android.app.Activity are in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @6e464f5e)
I am new to android and I don't really know what's going on here but from the stack trace it seems like the problem is with the 3 following lines
@Composable
fun SportsListAndDetails(
    uiState: SportsUiState,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues,
    selectedSport: Sport
) {
    Row {
        SportsList(
            sports = uiState.sportsList,
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier.weight(0.55f)
        )
        val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity   //error here
        SportsDetail(
            selectedSport = selectedSport,
            onBackPressed = { activity.finish() },
            contentPadding = contentPadding,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
    }
}

@Preview(device = Devices.TABLET)
@Composable
fun SportsListAndDetailsPreview() {
    SportsTheme {                                         //error here
        val viewModel: SportsViewModel = viewModel()
        val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
        SportsListAndDetails(                             //error here
            uiState = uiState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(24.dp),
            selectedSport = LocalSportsDataProvider.defaultSport
            )
    }
}


Does this answer your question? Jetpack Compose Preview Render Problem when casting LocalContext.current

I don't think so, most answers on that question suggest extracting the cause of the problem to another function. In my case viewModel isn't causing any problems. I started facing problems when I added LocalContext to my code which is already outside the preview function.

You try to cast the context to an Activity. Since in a Preview there doesn't exist an activity, the cast fails. Old hat, was already asked (and answered) plenty of times. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401294/jetpack-compose-close-application-by-button

@Leviathan so I either use a safe call or pass the function down from an activity right?

I would recommend the nullable safe cast.
