# JavaScript ES6 - Object Constructors task issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, oop, constructor

I'm finally doing an advanced course for React and have some pre-work stuff to complete.

The task description doesn't say what the exact result should be and my result doesn't seem right to me.

**The task:**

*Part 1*

Create a constructor for object `Client` with argument `name`.

This object is supposed to have the following attributes:

`name` and `orders` (array to store orders), and a method `addOrder(order)` (to add new orders to `orders`)

*Part 2*

Create a constructor for object `Order` with arguments `client` and `number`.

This object is supposed to have the following attributes:

`client` (related to the client) and `number` (order number)

*Part 3*

Check your code with the following:

```
const client1 = new Client("John");
const order1 = new Order(client1, "1");
const order2 = new Order(client1, "2");

client1.addOrder(order1);
client1.addOrder(order2);

console.table(client1.orders);
```

My code:

```js
class Client {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.orders = [];
  }

  addOrder(order) {
    this.orders.push(order);
  }
}

class Order extends Client {
  constructor(client, number) {
    super(client);
    this.number = number;
  }
}

const client1 = new Client("John");
const order1 = new Order(client1, "1");
const order2 = new Order(client1, "2");

client1.addOrder(order1);
client1.addOrder(order2);

console.table(client1.orders);
```

returns this (and I believe, for the correct code, `name` should be "John" and `orders` arrays shouldn't be there at all):

```
Array(2)
0: Order {name: Client, orders: Array(0), number: '1'}
1: Order {name: Client, orders: Array(0), number: '2'}
```

[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhnls.png)

Comment: `Order` should not extend `Client`. An order is not a kind of client.

Comment: `class Order extends Client` ? An order is *not* a client, right?

Comment: It seems like you need to bone up on basic OO principles. Subclassing represents the IS-A relationship. But the relationship between Client and Orders is HAS-A. That's implemented in the `orders` array in `Client`.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between "IS -A" relationship and "HAS-A" relationship in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36162714)

Comment: This test is weird. Why would you need to pass `client1` as argument when *creating* the order, and then have to call `addOrder` on `client1` to really make the link with that client?? This is a bad exercise.

Comment: @trincot Makes sense for the order to handle its own addition. A bit of a visitor vibe to it. EDIT: wait, I see that's not what the exercise actually suggested...

Comment: Thanks for your tips and good points there!
Indeed, the task is a bit weird, and I will soon find out what their real intention was.
Also, `client1.orders` returns endless loop from `client` as this also contains `orders` array - but the task required `client` object in `Object` class, not `client.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Order` should not be a subclass of `Client`. A client has an array of orders, and an order has an associated client, but neither is a kind of the other.

The HAS-A relationship is implemented using a property, so you just do `this.client = client;` in the `Order` constructor.

```js
class Client {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.orders = [];
  }

  addOrder(order) {
    this.orders.push(order);
  }
}

class Order {
  constructor(client, number) {
    this.client = client;
    this.number = number;
  }
}

const client1 = new Client("John");
const order1 = new Order(client1, "1");
const order2 = new Order(client1, "2");

client1.addOrder(order1);
client1.addOrder(order2);

console.log(client1.orders);
```