# Multiple Inheritance add values

Tags: python, sql, class

I have a database with 2 tables that consist of a list of regions on one and a list of projects in the other (organized by region).  I want to read the regions into a class and then read the projects by region to add to the class.

I have tried to set up a root class with a region class and a project class with inheritance but can't get the projects into the class.

```
class mvtrend:
    def __init__(self):
        self.regions =[]

    def add_region(self, region):
        self.regions.append(region)


class region(mvtrend):
    def __init__(self, item_id, name):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.name = name
        self.projects = []

    def add_project(self, project):
        self.projects.append(project)


class project(region):
    def __int__(self, project_id, proj_name):
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.proj_name = proj_name


# result of SQL query that fetches the project name by region

   result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result == None:
                break
            new_proj = project(i, result)
            MVTrend_array.regions.add_project(new_proj)[text])
```

Comment: This is not a case for use of inheritance - just create plain classes, inheriting from nothing, and have a "region" attribute in your "project", and a "objects" attribute on your region class. Later, as you get more proficient with the language, you can automate those so that when changes are made on one site, those are reflected on the other.

Comment: It looks like your code will produce an error.  Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: In addition to what the others said, you have a typo in `project` class. You probably meant `__init__` but you defined `__int__` method instead.

Comment: Is this an academic exercise? If not, be aware of the general preference for [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and multiple inheritance's [bad reputation](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/#inheriting-multiple-classes).

Comment: You would inherit `project` from `region` if there were an IS-A relationship between `region` and `project`. It seems that there is a HAS-A relationship between the two and so composition is the way to express this in Python. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162714/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-relationship-and-has-a-relationship-in).

Comment: I changed the type in the project class but tat didn't change the outcome.

Comment: sReg = str(region.name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\env\Projects\MVtrends_SQL\main.py", line 115, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Programming\Python\env\Projects\MVtrends_SQL\main.py", line 110, in main
    get_projects()
  File "E:\Programming\Python\env\Projects\MVtrends_SQL\main.py", line 101, in get_projects
    MVTrend_array.regions.add_project(new_proj)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add_project'

Comment: Line 101 is MVTrend_array.regions.add_project(new_proj)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77544456/edit) the question with your full error traceback.