# C++ template class operator for brackets and equal to insert and get element

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operators

hello i want to create simple array class to get value and insert value like `(array[0] = 4)` and this is my program but i have problem to use `[] =` in same time for insert

```
template <typename Param>
class arr
{
private:

    int Last_point = 0;
    Param Data[];

public:

    void& operator[]=(int Element_id, Param v)
    {
        Data[Element_id] = v;
    }

    Param& operator[] (int Element_id)
    {
        return Data[Element_id];
    }
};



void main()
{
    arr <int> Array;


    Array[1] = 555;

    cout << "Is(" << to_string(Array[1]) << ")" << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

is there any operator like ([]=)? or for this, i have to use which methods? also i want to get value if just used `[]`

Comment: See [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, `Param Data[]` is either invalid or makes a pointer. In either case, you'll need to specify a size somewhere. Did you want a fixed size, or were you going to allocate your elements on the heap? In either case, you'll need a proper copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and destructor.

Comment: my array maybe have more than 1 million element ... what should i do for default size !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are attempting for the `operator[]` functions is quite wrong. You need something like:

```
  // Version for non-const objects
  Param& operator[](std::size_t i)
  {
     return Data[i];
  }

  // Version for const objects
  Param const& operator[](std::size_t i) const
  {
     return Data[i];
  }
```

If you want to support arrays whose sizes are known at compile time, you can use:

```
template <typename Param, std::size_t N>
class arr
{
   private:

      Param Data[N];

   public:

      Param& operator[](std::size_t i)
      {
         return Data[i];
      }

      Param const& operator[](std::size_t i) const
      {
         return Data[i];
      }
};
```

If you want to support arrays whose sizes are known at run time, you can use the following. However, you need to be aware of [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and make sure to implement the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator properly.

```
template <typename Param>
class arr
{
   private:

      Param* Data;

   public:

      arr(size_t size) : Data(new Param[size]) {}
      ~arr() { delete [] Data; }

      Param& operator[](std::size_t i)
      {
         return Data[i];
      }

      Param const& operator[](std::size_t i) const
      {
         return Data[i];
      }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

- `Foo& operator[]` is sufficient for reading and writing.
- Include the size of the array as a template parameter, or replace `Param[]` with `std::vector<Param>`.
- [Use `size_t` instead of `int` for array index types.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/131833/2449857)
- You don't need to wrap `Array[1]` in `to_string` for output.
- [Don't use `void main`! The standard says `main` must be `int`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204483/2449857)
- [`void&` is not valid C++ either.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457963/2449857)

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Param, size_t Size> class arr {
private:
  Param Data[Size];
public:
  Param &operator[](size_t Element_id) {
    return Data[Element_id];
  }
};

int main() {
  arr<int, 3> Array;
  Array[1] = 555;
  cout << "Is(" << Array[1] << ")" << endl;
}
```

---

However, all that `arr` does in my snippet is be a less useful `std::array`!